# Create an instance of a custom class with views from an xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xib

I have some custom views that for various reasons could only be practically set up using a nib. Now I want to initialize these nibs, or create the views (objects) from these nibs. Doing so with the code below works, but I don't know which init methods are called when these are generated. I had to use the drawRect method to do various setup stuff.

```
NSArray *bundleL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nibName" owner:self options:nil];
                    for (id object in bundleL) {
                        if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]){
                            myObject = (MyClass *)object;
                        }
                    }
```

what is the difference between `myObject = (MyClass *)object;`, which "works" as opposed to `myObject = [myClass alloc]initWithSomeMethod];` which so far has not worked for me.

Comment: This is something too basic to be asked here. You need to learn the C and the Objective-C language properly before trying to do complex tasks. If you don't even understand the difference between pointer assignment and creating a new instance, then there are **a lot** of things to learn yet.

Comment: Why is it too basic to be asked here? The question is answerable, as you've shown yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[MyClass alloc] init]` returns a new instance of the class: an object that is different from what is in the XIB file. `myObject = object;` simply performs a simple pointer assignment - `myObject` and `object` will point to the very same object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a bit more investigation, I think the proper way to do what I want to do is as below:

```
CustomView *aview = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomXib" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:aview];
```